# How to manage Facebook login to avoid authentication frequently in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use following code for Facebook login and access user information like albums and pictures. I have set code to get access token using following code. Now, the problem is I need to get access token everytime when user open application. However, once user authenticate, application will not ask for authenticate until user close the application. But it will ask for authenticate again after user reopen application. This way user will frustrate if they will ask to authentication everytime they will try to access albums or any other things of facebook.

Is there anyway to skip this? I mean once user provided access of Facebook, application must not ask for login(authenticate). I will have access token but I don't know how to use to play with authentication. So, we can avoid authentication frequently.

My Code:

```
public class FacebookService : IFacebookService
{

    private readonly string[] permissions = { "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_photos" };

    public event EventHandler<FacebookUser> LoginCompleted;

    public string Token => AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString;

    public void Logout()
    {
        LoginManager manager = new LoginManager();
        manager.LogOut();
    }

    public void LogInToFacebook()
    {
        if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken == null)
        {
            ObtainNewToken(LogInToFacebook);
            return;
        }

        var fields = new[] { "name", "email", "birthday", "gender", "picture" };

        var query = $"/me?fields={string.Join(",", fields)}";
        var token = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString;
        var request = new GraphRequest(query, null, token, null, "GET");

        request.Start((connection, result, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                HandleError(error.LocalizedDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                var userInfo = result as NSDictionary;
                var id = userInfo["id"].ToString();
                var email = userInfo["email"].ToString();
                var name = userInfo["name"].ToString();
                var birthday = userInfo["birthday"].ToString();
                var gender = userInfo["gender"].ToString();
                var picture = ((userInfo["picture"] as NSDictionary)["data"] as NSDictionary)["url"].ToString();
                var args = new FacebookUser(id, email, name, birthday, gender, picture);
                LoginCompleted?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        });
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RequestAlbums(Action<FacebookAlbum[]> callback)
    {
        if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken == null)
        {
            ObtainNewTokenForAlbum(callback);
            return;
        }

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);
                var host = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"{host}me/albums");
                var data = JObject.Parse(json).First.First.ToString();
                var albums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookAlbum[]>(data);

                var getPhotosTasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();

                foreach (var album in albums)
                    getPhotosTasks.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => RequestPhotos(album)));

                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(getPhotosTasks.ToArray());
                callback(albums);
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                HandleError(ex1.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ObtainNewTokenForAlbum(Action<FacebookAlbum[]> callback)
    {
        var login = new LoginManager();

        login.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, null, (r, e) =>
        {
            if (e == null && !r.IsCancelled)
            {
                RequestAlbums(callback);
            }
            else
                HandleError(e?.LocalizedDescription);
        });
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RequestPhotos(FacebookAlbum album)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);

            try
            {
                var host = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"{host}{album.Id}/photos?fields=source,picture");
                var data = JObject.Parse(json)["data"].ToString();
                album.Photos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookPicture[]>(data);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                HandleError(exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ObtainNewToken(Action callback)
    {
        var login = new LoginManager();

        login.LogInWithReadPermissions(permissions, null, (r, e) =>
        {
            if (e == null && !r.IsCancelled)
                callback?.Invoke();
            else
                HandleError(e?.LocalizedDescription);
        });
    }

    private void HandleError(string messageDescription)
    {
        messageDescription = messageDescription ?? "Request was cancelled";
        _notificationService.DisplayNotification(messageDescription, Colors.d8Red);
    }
}
```

AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    UAirship.TakeOff();
    RegisterServices();
    SetupFacebookSDK();
    FFImageLoading.Forms.Touch.CachedImageRenderer.Init();
    var dummy = new FFImageLoading.Forms.Touch.CachedImageRenderer();

    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = false;
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);

    _networkManager = new NetworkManager();

    OverrideDefaultListViewCustomActionsColors();

    UAirship.Push.UserPushNotificationsEnabled = true;
    new PhotoAccessChecker();
    return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
}

void SetupFacebookSDK()
{
    FacebookProfile.EnableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true);
    FacebookSettings.AppID = "000000000049000";
    FacebookSettings.DisplayName = "MyProduct";
}

public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
    return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
}
```

Comment: Can it be that you are testing your solution on iOS simulator?

Comment: @EvZ Okay, I have tested on iOS simulator. Let me test in mobile as well.

Comment: The problem with iOS simulator is that it does not store anything in the keystore by default, some additional actions required for that. Let me know if it is your problem so I could answer ...

Comment: @EvZ Hi, I have tested with iPhone. It asks for authentication first time whenever I close the app completely. If I just minimize the app, it doesn't ask. But if I close the app, it ask me again. I think I should store the access token somewhere and use it again if AccessToken is null. But in this case I must play with all other parameters like Token expiry and all. Can you please suggest your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forgot initialize FBSDK in `AppDelegate`.

Check your code if `return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching (application, launchOptions);` has been executed in `FinishedLaunching`.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    Settings.AppID = appId;
    Settings.DisplayName = appName;
    // ...

    // This method verifies if you have been logged into the app before, and keep you logged in after you reopen or kill your app.
    return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching (application, launchOptions);
}

public override bool OpenUrl (UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
    // We need to handle URLs by passing them to their own OpenUrl in order to make the SSO authentication works.
    return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl (application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
}
```

Comment: I have added my code of AppDelegate in question. I think it's same. Can you please review and let me know if I am missing something? this line is extra in my code `FacebookProfile.EnableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true);`

Comment: I don't see this line `return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching (application, launchOptions);`

Comment: I have this line `return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);`  Should I use the code given by you?

Comment: Hi, My app terminates after changing last line. App launch --> Ask to for permission to send Notification and then black screen. I apologies, for some security reason, I didn't provide all the code. But now, I have added full code of my `FinishedLaunching` method.

Comment: If I use this line, it works: `return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);`

Comment: The link i provided above is for Xamarin.ios , about facebook login in Xamarin.forms you can refer to https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms